# Clang, std::next, libstdc++ and constexpr-ness

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, static-assert

Take the following code:

```
#include <array>

constexpr std::array<int, 10> a{};
static_assert(std::next(std::begin(a)) == std::begin(a) + 1);
```

With `-std=c++17` GCC compiles it flawlessly, but Clang complains that the expression is not an integral constant expression. It looks like that the problem is about the `std::next` which, however, should be `constexpr` in C++17.

Nevertheless, `std::next` is in the std library, not in the compiler itself, therefore there is something weird going on. And just to make things even better, the example compiles perfectly if you pass `-stdlib=libc++` to Clang.

What is going on? Who is wrong and who is right?

**EDIT**

The issue seems to be related to clang being *toolchain-ed* against GCC 7.2 inside godbolt. If you add the `--gcc-toolchain=/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot` parameter to the command line, everything works flawlessly. (Thanks to @einpoklum who reported the issue to godbolt -- I have been slower ;) )

**EDIT**

For everyone who consider that an old compiler should work for actual standard, sorry to say that the consideration is meaningless. I am talking about the last versions of both GCC and Clang. And the problem is reproducible with the trunk version of both. Older compilers are not relevant for this question (MSVC behaviour would be interesting, instead).

Comment: It's because `std::next` arguments are (can be) evaluated during run time whereas `static_assert` expects a strictly `constexpr` condition. Just because the function is marked as `constexpr` doesn't mean it can't be invoked as a _regular_ function.

Comment: @Ron In this case everything both `a` and the `std::begin` are `constexpr`, so it is fine -- everything marked `constexpr` _can_ be evaluated at runtime, not the opposite

Comment: Sorry @Ron, but since C++17 std::array::iterator is a literal type, and two literal values can be compared at compile-time. If not, `static_assert(std::begin(a) != std::end(a))` should not compile, but it works flawlessly...

Comment: Is `iterator.operator+()` a `constexpr` method?

Comment: Sorry again @Ron, as I said, [it compiles flawlessly](https://godbolt.org/g/tTiWHR)

Comment: It compiles only with the 7.3.0 version.

Comment: Have you look at header source ? maybe there is a preprocessor flag which make clang/gcc take different code.

Comment: The new answer is why you should always specify exactly which versions of compilers and stdlibs you used when writing posts like this. Just saying Clang or GCC means almost nothing considering how rapidly those evolve around the debut of a new C++ version.

Comment: @Ron - "Just because the function is marked as constexpr doesn't mean it can't be invoked as a regular function" But when invoked inside a `static_assert()`, can't be invoked run-time

Comment: @Jarod42 Honestly I did not check. Now I checked a bit, but everything looks fine at first glance. Maybe from a deeper analysis one could find a clue, but I am totally not a stdlib expert :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiling in Wandbox

```
#include <array>

int main()
 {
   constexpr std::array<int, 10> a{};
   static_assert(std::next(std::begin(a)) == std::begin(a) + 1);
 }
```

with clang++ 4.0.1 and command line

```
clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++1z
```

I get the error

```
prog.cc:6:18: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
   static_assert(std::next(std::begin(a)) == std::begin(a) + 1);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:6:18: note: non-constexpr function 'next<const int *>' cannot be used in a constant expression
/opt/wandbox/clang-4.0.1/include/c++/v1/iterator:599:1: note: declared here
next(_InputIter __x,
^
1 error generated.
```

But compiling with clang++ 5.0.0 (or 6.0.0 or 7.0.0 HEAD) with

```
clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17
```

So it seems a low support for C++17 in clang++ 4.0.1 (and/or libraries used by clang++), corrected in the following versions.

**-- EDIT --**

The problem is confirmed (see einpoklum's answer) for clang++ 5.0.0 and clang++ 6.0.0 in *gobold*.

So I suppose the problem is the version of libstdc++: seems that *gobold* is using a version (a older one, I suppose) where `std::next()` isn't defined as `constexpr` where *wandbox* is using a version where `std::next()` is `constexpr`.

Comment: I am always referring to the last version of compilers, in this case I tested it against both Clang 6.0 and Clang trunk, but [I get a compile error](https://godbolt.org/g/Q7wDit). Are you talking about using `-stdlib=c++`?

Comment: @dodomorandi - good question; answer modified adding the exact code compiled and the exact command line for clang++. No: not using `-stdlib=c++`. Please, can you add your exact and complete code and your command lines in your question?

Comment: @dodomorandi - Maybe you should add the exact versions of the (linux packages of the ?) libstdc++. You're right: seems a problem in the library: `std::next()` not defined `constexpr`. But if you're using the last version of g++ and clang++, are you sure you're using the last version of libstdc++?

Comment: Yes, they are compiled with the GCC, and _godbolt_ is having the same behaviour I am getting on my machine. Nevertheless, you are right -- Wandbox compiles it fine with clang! Now I am more confused than before... :s

Comment: @dodomorandi - I suppose that godbolt and wandbox are using different versions of libstdc++; a older one (without a `constexpr std::next()`) for gobold and a more recent (with a `constexpr std::next()`) for wandbox

Comment: @dodomorandi : max66 is right, see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/u4PJMW) for confirmation – Godbolt's Clang trunk is using a libstdc++ that is 8+ months old.

Answer (score 2):

With the Clang 6.0.0 and 5.0.0 version on GodBolt.org, your code does indeed [fail to compile](https://godbolt.org/g/fFif7e). But - with clang 5.0.0-3 on my system (Lubuntu 17.10), it seems to compile without errors.

This is weird behavior. So, perhaps not the best possible answer to your question, but faced with something like this I would report it on [bugs.llvm.org](https://bugs.llvm.org/) and see what the clang/LLVM developers say.

Comment: You made me suspicious, so I tried on my Arch Linux machine, and it compiles fine. You are right, something is really strange here (even because on the other machine I compiled both GCC and Clang manually, and I know that I did not specified any particular compilation flag). I'll take you suggestion of reporting the problem to bugs.llvm.org, even if it could depend on stdlibc++.

Comment: @dodomorandi: Don't you think it's weird the error messages seem to come from libstdc++ code? ... anyway, just filed a [bug](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/issues/903) against the GodBolt compiler explorer.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to something like compile-specific preprocessing instructions or similar. But on the other hand, if something like clang is using the stdlib, it must be able to use it as-it-is. So, you are probably right! ;)